# How to do this using \tcolorbox?

Tags: minipage, tcolorbox

I would like to create this box design, especially the two columns.

[image]

Comment: Read the manual? Even easier: read the code which produced this. Possibly these two suggestions are identical in practice.

Comment: It is in english... I don't speak english... help me please I dont understand something XD

Comment: What really matters is the option `sidebyside`: this turns the 'lower' part of the box (usually marked by `\tcblower`) so it is beside the main part of the box. As for the rest, I'm not sure what you are so eager to mimic. The blue colour? the shadow? the rounded corners? the marginal note that is overprinting the 'lower' part of the box?  ... In any event, you will likely find people are more eager to help if you show them what progress you have managed to make on your own, especially if it is in the form of a minimal `.tex` file.

Comment: The answers here are in english too. How will you understand them?

Answer (score 3):

You can just copy paste from the source files of the `tcolorbox` manual.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

%
% from tcolorbox.doc.s_main.sty
%

\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,
    marginparsep=3mm,marginparwidth=18mm,
    headheight=0mm,headsep=0cm,
    footskip=1.5cm,includeheadfoot%,showframe
    ]{geometry}

\lstdefinestyle{mydocumentation}{style=tcbdocumentation,
  classoffset=0,
  texcsstyle=*\color{blue},
  % LaTeX and other packages
  moretexcs={arrayrulecolor,draw,includegraphics,ifthenelse,isodd,lipsum,path,pgfkeysalso},
  classoffset=1,
  % tcolorbox macros
  moretexcs={% core
    endtcolorbox,endtcbverbatimwrite,newtcolorbox,newtcbox,newtcboxfit,tcbusetemp,tcbtitle,tcbtitletext,
    tcblower,tcbox,tcboxfit,tcbset,tcbuselibrary,tcolorbox,tcbverbatimwrite,tcbsetforeverylayer,tcbsubtitle,
    tcolorboxenvironment,tcblistof,tcbstartrecording,tcbrecord,tcbstoprecording,tcbinputrecords,
    tcbpatcharcangular,tcbpatcharcround,tcbifoddpage,thetcolorboxnumber,thetcolorboxpage,
    tcbheightfromgroup,tcbheightspace,tcbtextwidth,tcbtextheight,
    % listings
    endtcblisting,newtcblisting,newtcbinputlisting,
    tcblisting,tcbinputlisting,tcbuselistingtext,tcbuselistinglisting,tcbusetemplisting,
    tcbfitdim,tcbfitsteps,
    % raster
    thetcbrasternum,tcbitem,
    % theorems
    tcbmaketheorem,tcboxmath,tcbhighmath,thetcbcounter,newtcbtheorem,
    % documentation
    brackets,
    colDef,colOpt,cs,
    docAuxCommand,docColor,docAuxEnvironment,docAuxKey,
    docCounter,docLength,
    meta,marg,
    oarg,
    refCom,refEnv,refKey,
    tcbmakedocSubKey,tcbdocmarginnote,tcbdocnew,tcbdocupdated,
    % skins
    tcbincludegraphics,tcbincludepdf,pdfpages,imagepage,imagepath,imagename,
    tcbline,tcboxedtitleheight,tcboxedtitlewidth,
    tcbsettowidthofnode,tcbsetmacrotowidthofnode,tcbsettoheightofnode,tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode,
    % vignette
    tcbvignette,
    % xparse
    DeclareTColorBox,NewTColorBox,RenewTColorBox,ProvideTColorBox,
    DeclareTotalTColorBox,NewTotalTColorBox,RenewTotalTColorBox,ProvideTotalTColorBox,
    DeclareTCBox,NewTCBox,RenewTCBox,ProvideTCBox,
    DeclareTotalTCBox,NewTotalTCBox,RenewTotalTCBox,ProvideTotalTCBox,
    DeclareTCBListing,NewTCBListing,RenewTCBListing,ProvideTCBListing,
    DeclareTCBInputListing,NewTCBInputListing,RenewTCBInputListing,ProvideTCBInputListing,
    DeclareTCBoxFit,NewTCBoxFit,RenewTCBoxFit,ProvideTCBoxFit,
    DeclareTotalTCBoxFit,NewTotalTCBoxFit,RenewTotalTCBoxFit,ProvideTotalTCBoxFit,
    tcbsidebyside,tcboxverb,
    % externalization
    tcbEXTERNALIZE,tcbifexternal,newtcbexternalizeenvironment,
    renewtcbexternalizeenvironment,extcolorbox,extikzpicture,
    newtcbexternalizetcolorbox,renewtcbexternalizetcolorbox,
    tcbiffileprocess,
    % box array
    newboxarray,boxarraygetsize,boxarrayreset,boxarrayclear,
    boxarraygetbox,boxarraygetwidth,boxarraygetheight,boxarraygetdepth,
    boxarraygettotalheight,useboxarray,usetcboxarray,
    consumeboxarray,consumetcboxarray,
    },
  texcsstyle=*\color{Definition}\bfseries,
  classoffset=0% restore default
  }

\definecolor{Green_Dark}{rgb}{0.078431,0.407843,0.176471}
\definecolor{Blue_Dark}{rgb}{0.090196,0.211765,0.364706}
\definecolor{Blue_Bright}{rgb}{0.858824,0.898039,0.945098}

\tcbset{
  documentation listing style=mydocumentation,%
  sbs/.style={sidebyside,before lower app={\tcbset{sidebyside=false}}},%
  innerbox/.style={reset,documentation listing style=mydocumentation,
    docexample/.style={docexample original},%
    },
  beforeafter example/.style={
    before skip=4pt plus 2pt minus 1pt,
    after skip=8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt
  },
  base example/.style={bicolor,
    beforeafter example,arc is angular,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    fontlower=\footnotesize,
    colframe=Blue_Dark,
    colback=Blue_Bright,
    colbacklower=white,
    drop fuzzy shadow,
    },
  docexample/.style={base example,%
    every box on layer 2/.style={every box},
    before upper={\tcbset{innerbox}},before lower={\tcbset{innerbox}}
    },
  docexample original/.style={colframe=ExampleFrame,colback=ExampleBack,fontlower=\footnotesize,
    before skip=\medskipamount,after skip=\medskipamount,frame style={}},
}

\begin{document}

%
% from tcolorbox.doc.documentation.tex
%

\begin{dispExample*}{sidebyside}
\tcbdocnew{1981-10-29}.
% Next one is displayed in the margin:
\tcbdocmarginnote{\tcbdocnew{1978-02-09}}
\end{dispExample*}

\end{document}
```

[image]